# append fields dynamically at runtime based on user input in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, dynamic, runtime

In c# how would I best handle this scenario, a form contains a large number of checkboxes 100+ which map to columns/fields in the data store, and the user can select any of them. Depending on those they choose when they submit the form I will generate a csv output of the data but only showing the fields(columns) they have requested.

```
list myData = getAllTheData
var fieldstheychose = "name, mileage, address"

            foreach (var item in mydata)
                {
                var somedata = new StringBuilder();

                // make decision to include field or not
                somedata.Append(item.name.formatvalue() + ",");
                // make decision to include field or not
                somedata.Append(item.mileage.GetCSVEncodedValue() + ",");
                // make decision to include field or not
                somedata.Append(item.address.ToDisplayString() + ",");

                // make decision on 100+ fields that might be in the fieldstheychose list depending on their choices
        }
    return somedata;
```

I need to at runtime decide which fields will be appended above but I wanted to avoid 100+ if blocks to decide weather to append the data.

I did look at dynamic objects and expando objects but I'm not sure it helps in this scenario.

Any views appreciated.

Comment: Are these checkboxes on a winforms panel?

Comment: sorry no, I should have made this clear, they are an asp.net form

Comment: made some edits above to make it clear than until the user selects which fields they want to include at runtime, I don't know which item. value will need to be included without multiple if conditions and listing all 100 of them

Answer (score 0):

```
List<ListItem> selected = new List<ListItem>();
foreach (ListItem item in YourCheckBoxListID)
    if (item.Selected) 
        selected.Add(item);
```

This will store the ListItems that have been checked assuming you are using a `CheckBoxList`. From there you can iterate through your selected list and convert the entries into proper csv format.

Answer (score 0):

Give the name of the checkboxes same to what you have in the list mydata. Loop through the list and find your check-boxes using the findControl() function to get the checkbox checked Boolean value. Add it to the list.

Comment: So what I think you are trying to say is there are different data types for different fields. You can create a Dictionary in DB or in code to determine the type of conversion you want to make on different fields and then create the if conditions for each type.

Comment: yes your right, different data types for each string field value, I was trying as much as possible to reduce the number of if conditions, as there could be a large number of fields coming through from the page

Comment: Yeah you can achieve that using a dictionary of types